# Conversion from Ito equations to Stratonovich

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have the stochastic equations

$$
dx = pdt + \beta (x^2 + p)dV \\
dp = xdt - \gamma (x^3 + p^2)dW \\
$$

where $dV$ and $dW$ are mutually independent Wiener processes. I am asked to calculate the corresponding Stratonovich equations.

I know how to go from an Ito-integral to Stratonovich, but unsure what is meant by "calculating the corresponding Stratonovich equations". Can anybody shed light on this?

Comment: This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182952/the-transformation-from-ito-integral-to-stratnonvich-integral/3189906#3189906) can help you.

Comment: @Sesame Thanks. Could you help me get started on this? Not sure where to begin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

> Assume $n$-dimensional Ito process $\mathbf{X}$ which  has the following dynamics:
>   \begin{equation}
> d\textbf{X}_t = \textbf{b}(\textbf{X}_t,t)dt + \textbf{B}(\textbf{X}_t, t)d\textbf{W}_t
> \end{equation}
>   where $\mathbf{b}$ : $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{B}: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
>
> It exits an equivalent dynamic using the Stratonovich integral:
>   \begin{equation}
> d\textbf{X}_t = \mathbf{\tilde{b}}(\textbf{X}_t,t)dt +\textbf{B}(\textbf{X}_t, t)\circ d\textbf{W}_t
> \end{equation}
>   where
>   \begin{equation}
> \left[\mathbf{\tilde{b}}(\textbf{X}_t,t)\right]^i= \left[\mathbf{b}(\textbf{X}_t,t)\right]^i
> -\frac12\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial{B}^{i,k}(\textbf{X}_{t},t)}{\partial x_j}{B}^{j,k}(\textbf{X}_{t},t)dt
> \end{equation}

In your case, we have $\mathbf{X}_t = \{x_t,p_t\}$. I will let you define  $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.